# how to install a specific version on tensorflow docker image

Tags: docker, tensorflow

dear a I am trying to install tensorflow-gpu docker image a specific one tensorflow 1.6
I have tried to use the tag version like this

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:version:1.6.0-gpu
```

unfortunately it does not work it says the "invalid reference format" I have searched for that but nothing comes up... please your kind support

Comment: I once used this image [tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu-py3](https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/1.6.0-gpu-py3/images/sha256-0f4b997bc3af4caa3b700552bf295dde3a6a36c4816ff036d0ddd1632e73cb52). Try pulling this one if it's still stable. The command though will be `docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu-py3 `. [Doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-an-image-from-docker-hub)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow docker container for 1.6 GPU version

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:1.6.0-gpu
```

For more information visit [Tensorflow docker site](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=23&ordering=last_updated). Thanks